# How do I select the first instance of a string and delete the entire row

Tags: vba, excel

The code below picks a random item from a list

```
Sub Rand()
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kudo Prize").Range("B1").Formula = Evaluate("=INDEX(Lista!$A:$A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Lista!$A:$A)))")
End Sub
```

it works perfect but I want to add something so the macro can delete the item from the list the items repeat themselves several times so i want to delete just one instance say for example the result in B1 is "Coffe" I want the macro to find the first instance of "Coffe" in the "Lista" sheet and delete the whole row

Comment: Why do you need VBA Code for this? You could use `AutoFilter | Contains` and then delete the row of the first instance? If you still need VBA then you could use `.Find` as shown [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Look at using the `Range.Find()` method.

Comment: I need a VBA Code because I need it to run by clicking an Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Macro Man suggests you can use range.find() for the matching, you can use cells.EntireRow.Delete to remove the row.
I can't imagine what you are going to actually use this function for...

```
Sub Rand()
 Dim value_to_find As String
 Dim row_number As Integer
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kudo Prize").Range("B1").Formula = Evaluate("=INDEX(Lista!$A:$A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Lista!$A:$A)))")
 value_to_find = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kudo Prize").Range("B1").Text
 row_number = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").Range("A:A").Find(value_to_find).Row
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").Cells(row_number, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: That does make some sense. If it works, please could you mark it as the answer :)